# How to check for broken links and save the result in excel using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to get all the links in a web page and store it in first column in excel sheet and check whether the link is broken are valid and update the result in second column in same excel sheet.

Here is the code I have tried,

```
public class login {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void login1() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver path");

        driver.get("url");
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    }
@Test
    public void data() throws IOException {
        File src = new File("excel path");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet Sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Sheet1.createRow(0).createCell(0);
        List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        String url = "";
        HttpURLConnection huc;
        int respCode = 200;
        int cell =0;
        for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++) {
            WebElement alinks = links.get(i);
            String allinks = alinks.getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(allinks);
            XSSFRow row = Sheet1.createRow(i);
            XSSFCell excelCell = row.createCell(cell);
            excelCell.setCellValue(allinks);

        }
         Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();
         while(it.hasNext()){
           url = it.next().getAttribute("href");
           System.out.println(url);
           if(url == null || url.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("URL is not yet published");
                            continue;
                        }
           try {
               huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());

               huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

               huc.connect();

               respCode = huc.getResponseCode();
               for (int i=1; i <= Sheet1.getLastRowNum(); i++){
                   Cell resultCell= Sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1); 

               if(respCode >= 400){
                   System.out.println(url+" is a broken link");
                   resultCell.setCellValue("FAIL");
               }
               else{
                   System.out.println(url+" is a valid link");
                   resultCell.setCellValue("PASS");
               }
               }

           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(src);
        wb.write(fout);
    }
```

With this code I can able to get all the links from the web page and store it in first column of excel sheet but when checking for broken links only the first link is checked and before checking second link it throws java.lang.NullPointerException error at this line resultCell.setCellValue("PASS");  Can any one help on this?

Comment: From where it is throwing NPE? It would be helpful if you elaborate and provide more information to this

Comment: It throws java.lang.NullPointerException error at this line resultCell.setCellValue("PASS");  @AkshayVasava

Answer (score 0):

In the above case, the cell does not exist yet, so `getCell` returns `null`.

You must detect this and create the cell if it doesn't exist, with [`createCell`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#createCell(int)) method:

```
Cell resultCell= Sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1);
if (cell == null)
{
    cell = Sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(1);
}
// Then set the value.
cell.setCellValue("PASS");
```

Alternatively, there is an overload of [`getCell`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell(int,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy)) where you can specify a `MissingCellPolicy` so that a blank `Cell` is automatically created if it didn't already exist:

```
cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```